Prices numbers in English numbers
I'm working on Magento 2 V2.4.6 and I'm facing a problem with prices numbers, in the other store view like Arabic ( the numbers changed to Arabic numbers while I need it to still in English numbers ).
I've tried the solution of overring ( price-utils.js ) but it's changed the price number in product page only not in the whole stie.
Could you please help me with this.
Please note I've another store V2.4.2 and the numbers still in English even in Arabic store view.
Thanks in advance.

Certainly! Let's go through the steps more precisely to ensure you can make the necessary changes to display English numbers across the entire site, including the Arabic store view.
1. Override price-utils.js Globally
Create the Directory Structure

Navigate to your Magento root directory.

Create the following directory structure for your custom theme:
app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[Theme]/web/js

Replace [Vendor] with your vendor name and [Theme] with your theme name.


Copy price-utils.js

Copy price-utils.js from the Magento module to your theme:
cp vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/web/js/price-utils.js app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[Theme]/web/js/price-utils.js



Modify price-utils.js

Open the copied price-utils.js file in your editor.

Find the formatPrice function. It typically looks like this:
define([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    'use strict';

    var priceUtils = {
        // existing code here
        formatPrice: function (amount, format, isShowSign) {
            // existing format logic
            var formattedPrice = //... your existing formatted price logic

            return formattedPrice;
        }
        // more existing code here
    };

    return priceUtils;
});


Modify the formatPrice function to include the Arabic to English number conversion:
define([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    'use strict';

    var priceUtils = {
        formatPrice: function (amount, format, isShowSign) {
            // Your existing code here

            // Add this function to convert Arabic numbers to English numbers
            function convertToEnglishNumbers(str) {
                var arabicToEnglishMap = {
                    '٠': '0', '١': '1', '٢': '2', '٣': '3', '٤': '4', '٥': '5', '٦': '6', '٧': '7', '٨': '8', '٩': '9'
                };
                return str.replace(/[٠-٩]/g, function (d) {
                    return arabicToEnglishMap[d];
                });
            }

            // Use the original formatting logic
            var formattedPrice = // your existing formatted price logic

            // Apply the conversion
            formattedPrice = convertToEnglishNumbers(formattedPrice);

            return formattedPrice;
        }
    };

    return priceUtils;
});



2. RequireJS Configuration
To make sure your custom price-utils.js is used instead of the default one, you need to configure RequireJS:

Create or edit the requirejs-config.js file in your custom theme directory:
app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[Theme]/requirejs-config.js


Add the following configuration:
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'priceUtils': 'js/price-utils'
        }
    }
};



The warning "config is assigned a value but never used" is typically a linting warning that you can ignore in this context because RequireJS will use the config object to map the custom price-utils.js file.
3. Locale Configuration
Check your locale settings to ensure that the correct locale is set for your Arabic store view:

Go to Stores > Configuration > General > Locale Options.
Make sure the locale is set appropriately for your Arabic store view.

4. Clear Cache and Deploy Static Content
After making these changes, clear the cache and deploy the static content to ensure the changes take effect:
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

By following these steps, you should be able to ensure that the price numbers are displayed in English across the entire site, regardless of the store view language. If you encounter any issues, please let me know, and I can provide further assistance.

Hi @amal, thank you for your kind assistance.
Unfortunately it didn't solved.. the requirejs-config.js already called when I check through network in my browser.
I think price-utils.js not modified well because my original file is different not like the sample which you shared.

Please find my price-utils.js file in this link:
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/r7uyl159mlerytx2l6gxo/price-utils.js?rlkey=vpysj1n2sqg8pb0l4nq05f7co&st=rut9qxrx&dl=0

Dear @amal, could you please explain what's the value here >>
var formattedPrice = // your existing formatted price logic
